# SocketException 'the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time' when connecting to server using public ip (C#)

Tags: c#, network-programming, system.net, system.net.sockets

I'm trying to create a server using C#. Currently, I have two programs, a server and a client both of which work correctly when they are both run on the same computer, the server's `TcpListener` is created using the ip 127.0.0.1 (localhost) and the client connects to the ip 127.0.0.1. However, when I try to  connect to the server using my public ip, the client program waits about 20 seconds and then I get a `SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond`

I have already port-forwarded the port I am using (the port is 2345). I tried the same steps as above on a different computer but I still got the same result. I tried using the public ip when creating the server's `TcpListener` but then I got `SocketException: The requested address is not valid in its context` so I'm assuming that I should just use 127.0.0.1 (I could be wrong though, this is my first time trying something like this).

Here's the function for creating the server.

```
public static void RunServer()
{
    string ipStr = "";
    Console.WriteLine("Enter IP...");
    ipStr = Console.ReadLine();
    if (ipStr == "localhost")
        ipStr = "127.0.0.1";
    IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(ipStr);

    int port = -1;
    Console.WriteLine("Enter port...");
    while (port == -1)
    {
        try
        {
            port = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter an integer.");
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Starting server on " + ip + ":" + port);

    TcpListener tcpListener;
    try
    {
        tcpListener = new TcpListener(ip, port);
        tcpListener.Start();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e);
        Console.ReadLine();
        return;
    }

    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            TcpClient tcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();

            NetworkStream networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(networkStream);
            string msg = sr.ReadToEnd();

            Console.WriteLine("Received message: \"" + msg + "\"");

            sr.Close();
            networkStream.Close();
            tcpClient.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

And the function for creating the client.

```
public static void RunClient()
{
    string ip = "";
    Console.WriteLine("Enter IP...");
    ip = Console.ReadLine();

    int port = -1;
    Console.WriteLine("Enter port...");
    while (port == -1)
    {
        try
        {
            port = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter an integer.");
        }
    }

    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter message...");
        string msg = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Sending message: \"" + msg + "\"");

        TcpClient tcpClient;
        try
        {
            tcpClient = new TcpClient(ip, port);
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Could not connect to server. Connection refused.");
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e);
            continue;
        }

        NetworkStream networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();

        networkStream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg), 0, msg.Length);
        Console.WriteLine("Sent message!");

        networkStream.Close();
        tcpClient.Close();
    }
}
```

I thought that what I have currently would work, but all I get is that exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the line `IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(ipStr);` of the server program should have been `IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Any;`

Comment: Perfect answer, saved me hours!

Answer (score 0):

This is because your computer's firewall is preventing the connection. In your firewall's inbound rule add exception for the port you are using.

Comment: I tried adding a rule for the port and the program but neither worked. Also, the port I'm using is 2345 if that matters.